# read and append inside a post node express

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have a node app structured like this:

- tlc-rest-api

  - api

    - db
    - routes

Inside the db folder I have a JSON file named apartments.json that looks like this:

```
      [
         {
            "id": 0,
            "address": "Not set"
         },
         {
            "id": 1,
            "address": "Not set"
         }
      ]
```

In routes folder I have a router with a post method:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const apartments = require("../db/apartments.json");

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {

   // read request
   let apa = {
       id: req.body.id,
       address: req.body.address
   };

   // todo: add new apartment here...

});

module.exports = router;
```

What I want to achieve is read the file, create an array, push apa object to that array and store back the json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that JSON calls doesn't work inside post because stringify() returns [object Object], this is my solution

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {

  let apa = {
      id: req.body.id,
      address: req.body.address
 }

 let apas = [];
 let apartments = require('path/to/json');
 apas.push(apa);
 let str = "[ ";
 for(let i = 0; i < apas.length - 1; i++) {
    strAlt += '{"id": ' + apas[i].id + ', "name": "' + apas[i].name + '"}, ';
}
strAlt += '{"id": ' + apas[apas.length - 1].id + ', "name": "' + apas[apas.length - 
1].name + '"} ] ';
console.log("hard coded stringify: " + strAlt);
fs.writeFile("path/to/json", strAlt, (err) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("file saved!");
});
console.log(apartments);
res.status(200).send(apa);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the JSON file with `fs` module.

```js
fs.readFile('path/to/json', (data) => {
  const parsed = JSON.parse(data)
  // just imagine that arr is an array that you wan to push
  let newArr;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    const element = arr[i]
    newArr = parsed.push(element)
  }
  fs.writeFile('path/to/json', JSON.stringify(newArr), (success) => {
    res.send({ success })
  })
})
```

for confenient if you want to ho to other folder you should create their dirname

```
// on the folder
exports const jsondir = __dirname

module.exports.jsondir = jsondir
```

and just require it.